# Prevent activity from closing due to click on Up/home in action bar?

Tags: android, android-activity

How can I prevent the activity from being closed, if the user clicks on the Up/Home button (in the action bar, not the physical one)?
I tried to do something like this as a first approach, but even the modal dialog is swept away:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {

    final int id = item.getItemId();
    if (android.R.id.home == id) {

        (new AlertDialog.Builder(this))
                .setMessage("Do you really want to quit ?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // @TODO: don't stop activity
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

        }).setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // @TODO: stop activity
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }}).show();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: public **boolean** onOptionsItemSelected + docs should help ... also  dialog show is not blocking ...

Comment: Try to add a `return true;` at the end of your  `if`. It will avoid the default behavior to be called...

Comment: thx, forgot to return true :-), this one works

Comment: you always should return true if android.R.id.home == id ... but in positive button click listener you  should call finish() ...

Comment: Selvin, thx for your hint, I was about to return "false" in the positive listener, but your suggestions seems better to me ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example. The code explains itself.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
    final int id = item.getItemId();
    if (android.R.id.home == id) {
        (new AlertDialog.Builder(this))
                .setMessage("Do you really want to quit ?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        finish(); // finish activity
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .show();
        return true; // true = handled manually (consumed)
    } else {
        // Default behaviour for other items
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In OptionsItemSelected if you return true instead of the constructor inside each of the switch case statements for each button, your behavior will be the one that is run, and not the default one.